# Flutter / Dart: Problem Using the Spread Operator After The Else Clause Of A Ternary

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app, I'm trying to use the Dart spread operator (ie-...) at the else section of a ternary operator in the build() method of one of my widgets.

ie-

```
class SearchCriteriaState extends State<SearchCriteria> {
  List<SearchParameters> listSearchParam = [];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
       children: [
         Text('hey there'),
         listSearchParam.isEmpty 
           ? Text ('Empty
           : ...listSearchParam.map((param)=>Text(param.toString()).toList(),
       ],
    );
  }
}
```

The code above will not compile, getting the error below with the spread statement underlined in red.

```
Expected to find ','.dart(expected_token)
```

If I replace the whole ternary with just the spread statement, it will compile and  run (except it doesn't deal with the edge condition where the list is empty).

Any ideas?

The workaround I'm using currently is to wrap the spread statement in another Column() which works, but is fugly ('scuse my French).

I had already searched for similar issues and the closest I could find was also a problem with using the spread operator in a ternary but in the context of webpack which I'm assuming is with React.

All suggestions much appreciated.

/Joselito

Comment: Forgot to mention my environment:

Flutter 1.22.5

Mac OS Catelina 10.15.7

Comment: You forgot to close the bracket for the text widget. It should be ``listSearchParam.isEmpty ? Text('Empty') : ....``

Comment: yes, that is what I meant. It was typo on my part.

fyi @rickimaru gave a suggestion that worked, which was to replace the ternary with a full blown if-else statement.

Answer (score 10):

Please use `if else`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> texts = <String>['1', '2', '3'];
    final bool test = false;

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            const Text('asdf'),
            if (test)
              const Text('test is TRUE')
            else
              ...texts.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, rickimaru, for the suggestion, but the import of the material package is already there, I just forgot to include it when I wrote the post.

The problem is still there even with the import statement.

Comment: @Jose The problem is not the `import` statement. Please reread my answer. Refer to line `if (test)`.

Comment: Sorry, rickimaru, but I misread your suggestion. Will try it now, although I wasn't aware it was possible to use the 'if else' in place of the ternary in this context.

Comment: @Jose No probs. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: your suggestion worked. Thanks!

I didn't think to replace the ternary with an if-else cuz I tried that in the past and it wouldn't compile. Would you know if that is something new with 1.22.5?

Comment: @Jose Nice! I think this kind of conditioning in list and map already exist before 1.22.5. I've been using this kind of checking since last year.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `... condition ? then_list : else_list,` would also work.  You need to get into "gathering values for a spread" mode before you start the ternary.